# issue with script password check

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to check password on my form password changer but not sorting it  see below my code its not responding and submit buton steel disabled

html :

```
<form name="resetform" action="login/change.php" id="resetform" class="passform" method="post" role="form">
    <h3>Change Your Password</h3>
    <br />
    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo $sname; ?>" ></input>
    <label>Enter Old Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control field" name="currentPassword" id="old_password">
    <label>Enter New Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control field" name="newPassword" id="new_password">
    <label>Confirm New Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control field"  name="con_newpassword"  id="con_newpassword" />
    <br>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="updatepass" id="submit_btn" disabled value="Change Password" />
</form>
```

script :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.field input').keyup(function() {

        var empty = false;
        $('.field input').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
                empty = true;
            }
        });

        if (empty || !($('#new_password').val() === $('#con_newpassword').val())) {
            $('#submit_btn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {

            $('#submit_btn').attr('disabled', false);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Class name wrong `.field input` to `.passform input`

```
 $('.passform input').keyup(function () {

                var empty = false;
                $('.passform input').each(function () {
                    if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
                        empty = true;
                    }
                });
                if (empty || !($('#new_password').val() === $('#con_newpassword').val())) {
                    $('#submit_btn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                } else {

                    $('#submit_btn').attr('disabled', false);
                }
            });
```

Comment: `input.field` would work better as your selector will also catch the hidden field and button